# data/log folder causes "internal storage has run out of space" message

Tags: internal-storage

So all of a sudden I'm seeing the dreaded "storage space running out" message. I'm running the nightlies of cyanogemod 10 on galaxy s2.

I looked into the storage manager and the numbers didn't add up.

Couldn't find any app that shows you content of internal storage (they all work on the SD), so I used the terminal emulator to view the files myself (requires super user permissions).

I found out that there is a directory data/log that takes a lot of memory, about 1 GB. From viewing the files in it it appears to have a lot of log files with names such as dumpstate_RESET_BY_CP_SILENTRESET...

What is this? Can I delete everything there?

EDIT:
found this http://forum.cyanogenmod.org/topic/71465-log-directory-full-of-dumpstate-files/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just deleted it... it seems to be a bug with cyanogenmod. Will update if there are any problems.

Deletion was done through the terminal app. You type `su` to give it super user permissions, then you go to the path and use a linux command to delete the files.

Comment: On the forum, I suggested for them to post a bug report on https://jira.cyanongenmod.org, but as far as I know, this hasn't been done yet. If the developers aren't aware of the problem, they can't fix it (they don't frequent the forums).

Comment: You can use ES file explorer to delete these file also.

Comment: so it seems safe to delete `/data/log` completely to free up internal memory of my `galaxy Y`? I wonder if there is an application to automatically do that? I wonder if link2sd could link that folder to sdcard...

Comment: I believe you need root permissions for that.

Comment: in my fairphone, it was /data/log_other_mode but same thing otherwise